# Brown strawberry Leaf

Tags: plant-health, plant-care, watering, strawberries

[image]

[image]

Greetings, newly planted strawberry plants..some are flowering while others have a brownish colour towards the edge of the leaf. Need to know the reason for the brown leaves. Appreciated.

PS: I live in the Middle East (Beirut Lebanon) it’s autumn now,I’m using a nylon cover to keep the plants warm.